# How to ask for multiple lines of input and print them out as a list in Python

Tags: input, multiline

How do I write a code which prints out multiple lines of input and prints it back as a line? The inputs should look something like this

Enter participant 1: Jack

Enter participant 2: Jill

…

Enter participant 6: Joshua

```
lanes = int(5)
inputs = [] 
for x in range(loops): 
    inputs.append(input("Enter participant ", x))
```

I went all the way till here to store the values but wasnt sure how to print a different line each time

Answer (score 0):

Python inputs takes in one argument, and you can loop it for as many participants as you want.

```
inputs = [] 
for x in range(1, 7) #starts from 1 and loops till 7: 
    inputs.append(input("Enter participant " + str(x) + ": ")) 

print(inputs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).